# C socket and malloc/mutex crash

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pointers

I'm trying to build a multi-client and multi-server program in C. Let's me explain: 
1)N-clients could connect and send information (s_packets)
2)N-servers could connect and get this information (yes, our external server will connect to this program to receive data sent by the clients)
3) The servers that will connect to my program will not send anything, just receive data sent by clients.

Now the problem: I'm getting random errors in function malloc(). This is what I'm doing:
In the main function, I create all mutex that I'll need and start 2 threads: waitNewClients and waitNewServers. 
waitNewClients will wait (accept) for client connection and when client is connected, start a thread called handle_connection. waitNewServers will do the same, but when server is connected, new thread called server_handle in created.

Globally, I have this:

```
     struct s_packets {
        char callsign[30];
        char c_key[33];
        struct s_packets *next;
    };

    struct s_servers {
        int8_t               active;
        char                ip[50];
        int32_t             port;
        pthread_t           s_thread;
        int                 *socket;
        struct s_packets    *packets;
    };
struct s_servers serverList[MAX_SERVERS];
```

And this is the function to create a new client, when it connects:

```
void *waitNewClients(void *arg) {

    int socket_desc, client_sock, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(30008);

    //Bind
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);


    while ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t*) & c))) {

        pthread_t thread_id;
        new_sock = (int *) malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        // puts("Connection accepted");
        printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n", client_sock, inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));
        enable_keepalive(client_sock);

        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, connection_handler, (void*) new_sock) < 0) {
            perror("could not create thread");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        // pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0) {
        perror("accept failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Now, in the connection_handle, code is:

```
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc) {
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*) socket_desc;
    size_t buf_idx = 0;
    char buf[BUFFLEN] = {0};
    int read_size;
    static uint64_t next_update;
    uint64_t now = mstime();
    int timeout = 0;
    int abort = 0;
    char temp_char;
    char * s_key = malloc(33);
    short *c_key_validated = malloc(2);
    char * c_serial = malloc(30);
    int32_t *c_version = 0;


    *c_key_validated = 0;
    next_update = now + 1000;
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_client_count);
    client_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_client_count);

    airnav_log_level(9, "[client_socket] Socket value: %d\n", sock);

    // Initial com
    while (!abort) {

        read_size = recv(sock, &temp_char, 1, MSG_PEEK);

        if (read_size > 0) { // The size os initial com packet is 41            

            if (buf_idx < BUFFLEN && (read_size = recv(sock, &temp_char, 1, 0) > 0)) {

                if (temp_char == '\n') {                    
                    procPacket(buf, socket_desc, s_key, (int32_t*) c_version, c_key_validated, c_serial); // Proccess the package                                        
                    memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof (buf)); // Clear the buffer
                    buf_idx = 0;
                    temp_char = 0;
                } else {
                    buf[buf_idx] = temp_char;
                    buf_idx++;
                    temp_char = 0;
                }

                timeout = 0;
            } else {
                airnav_log_level(6, "[client_socket] Buffer Cheio!\n");
            }

        } else {

            usleep(10000);
            now = mstime();
            if (now >= next_update) {
                next_update = now + 1000;
                timeout++;
                airnav_log_level(6, "[Key: %s] Timeout...%d\n", s_key, timeout);
                //airnav_log_level(9,"[client_socket] Socket value (timeout): %d\n",sock);
            }

            if (timeout >= CLIENT_TIMEOUT) {
                abort = 1;
            }

        }


    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_client_count);
    client_count--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_client_count);
    airnav_log("Client disconnected\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and in the end of procPacket, this is what I do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m_data_packet_count);
        data_packet_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_data_packet_count);

        // Only save packet if key is validated
        if (*key_validated == 1) {

            // For every server listening
            struct s_packets *s1;            
            for (int sc = 0; sc < MAX_SERVERS; sc++) {

                // Is this server active?
                if (serverList[sc].active == 1) { // Yes, then queue msg
                    airnav_log_level(7, "Servidor %d ativo! Adicionando msg...\n", sc);
                    s1 = malloc(sizeof (struct s_packets));
                    strcpy(s1->callsign, p_callsign);
                    //strcpy(s1->c_key, c_key);                    
                    s1->next = serverList[sc].packets;
                    serverList[sc].packets = s1;

                } else {
                    airnav_log_level(7, "Servidor %d offline!\n", sc);
                }


            }            


        }
```

On the server handle function, I do almost the same of connection_handle, but a little different :)
What I do is: 
1) lock mutex of serverlist;
2) Copy pointer of serverList packets to local pointer
3) Clear pointer of serverList packets 
4) unclock mutex
5) Send packets of local pointer to server connected in this handle.

This is working fine, but if I connect/disconnect 3~4 server very fast, my program simples crash with error in malloc of 'procPackets'!

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff3192700 (LWP 23449)]
_int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7fffe4000020, bytes=bytes@entry=72) at malloc.c:3367
3367        while ((pp = catomic_compare_and_exchange_val_acq (fb, victim->fd, victim))
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7fffe4000020, bytes=bytes@entry=72) at malloc.c:3367
#1  0x00007ffff6567fbc in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=72) at malloc.c:2893
#2  0x00000000004033b8 in procPacket (packet=packet@entry=0x7ffff3190de0 "", socket_=socket_@entry=0x7fffec0008c0, c_key=c_key@entry=0x7fffe40008c0 "5c1d413807f961f5e331d03be5201c0e",
    c_version=c_version@entry=0x0, key_validated=key_validated@entry=0x7fffe40008f0, sn=sn@entry=0x7fffe4000910 "") at rbrpiserver.c:937
#3  0x0000000000403676 in connection_handler (socket_desc=0x7fffec0008c0) at rbrpiserver.c:668
#4  0x00007ffff7bc8dc5 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff3192700) at pthread_create.c:308
#5  0x00007ffff65df73d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:113
```

Wha am I missing? :(
I can't see what could be wrong here.
This is part of code from server_handle:

```
// Let's clear the incoming buffer, if exists
        *read_size = recv(*sock, temp_char, 4096, MSG_DONTWAIT);
        airnav_log_level(5, "READ-SIZE for slot %d: %d, sock value: %d, sock address: %p\n", *slot, *read_size,*sock,sock);
        if (*read_size != 0) { // Connection still active
            *timeout = 0;

            *cou = 0;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m_server_list);
            local_list = serverList[*slot].packets;
            serverList[*slot].packets = NULL;
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_server_list);

            p_tmp1 = local_list;
            while (p_tmp1 != NULL) {

                if (*lost == 0) {
                    if (sendServerSocketPacket(socket_desc, p_tmp1) == -1) {
                        *lost = 1;
                        *abort = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    *abort = 1;
                }
                p_tmp2 = p_tmp1;
                p_tmp1 = p_tmp1->next;
                free(p_tmp2);
                p_tmp2 = NULL;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_server_list);

            if (p_tmp1 != NULL) {
                free(p_tmp1);
                p_tmp1 = NULL;
            }
            local_list = NULL;
            sleep(SERVER_SOCKET_SEND_TIME); // Replace with function that send data to the client
            *now = mstime();
        } else {

            sleep(1);
            *now = mstime();
            if (*now >= *next_update) {
                *next_update = *now + 1000;
                *timeout = *timeout + 1;
                airnav_log_level(5, "Timeout [server %d]...%d\n", *slot, *timeout);
            }

            if (*timeout >= SERVER_TIMEOUT) {
                *abort = 1;
                airnav_log_level(5, "[server %d] Timeout esgotado! Saindo...\n", *slot);
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE:** 
BTW, i found the problem. In the server_handle, in the end of connection/function, I was clearing the socket of serverlist socket......then, when a new 'server-client' sockets connect and I try to re-use this item of list, the socket isn't created anymore! When client connect, I don't malloc space for this socket in serverList.socket, since it should be already allocated......but I was 'freeyng(?)' this socket when 'server-client' disconnect....dumb! The only strange thing is that error is nothing related to this function. I have removed the cleaning code from server_handle and it's working perfectly now!

Comment: `while ((client_sock = accept(...` accept() returns -1 on error. zero is a valid return. And -1 returns from read() and recv() are not always errors. Check errno .

Comment: `new_sock = (int *) malloc(1);` don't do this.

Comment: in my tests, return of "0" in recv() means that client is disconnected. I've tested with a lot of clients (putty, RAW, telnet) in different platforms and itr's working. Since this 'server-client' doesn't send any data, it's the only way to detect timeout from this connection (and error while swnding data....but if I don't have data to send, I have no way to detect timeout!).

Comment: If `malloc` segfaults you are probably writing outside allocated memory. Look through all allocations/deallocations and writes ti allocated memory. Consider using Valgrind to help localise the problem.

Comment: often if your code is crashing `malloc` it's because of some other part of the code trashing the memory - it's worth running your code under something like "valgrind" or "electricfence" to see if you have any buffer overruns etc...

Comment: I'm sorry but there is really too much code here... Could you try to strip it down to a [mcve]. If you cannot first use valgring or electricfence to narrow the problem.

Comment: Use select() or poll() instead of MSG_PEEK. And IMHO you should fix the trivial errors before even thinking about threads.